# Why did I fail in using this restoration potion glitch?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

The way I **thought** how it works is the following.

1. Drink potion of restoration
2. Equip fortify alchemy gears
3. I will get improved alchemy forever (as long as I keep the gear).
4. Make better potion of restoration potion
5. Remove gears
6. Go back to #1 with the better restoration potion

I tried that my self. And something way off happens.

As the video suggest. There is no difference between I drink potion 90% fortify restoration and then equip the gear or drinking the potion of restoration while wearing the gear.

I can drink all potion of restoration (I got 3) and got 900% fortify restoration. In fact, drinking potion of restoration improves the effect of next potion of restoration. However, it **doesn't** improves the effect of fortify enchanting potion.

I did build awesome 260% fortify restoration potion. However, that potion only have 260% effect for 60 seconds. After that the potion that is already made drop to the regular 100% fortify restoration.

So it's as if I am not really making more powerful potion. It's just the same potion but with temporary higher effect.

So where did I do wrong?

Drinking restoration potion and then equipping fortify alchemy gears do not help at all.

The main difference between drinking and then equip, compared to drinking while already wearing the 4 fortify alchemy set is in the active effect screen. In active effect screen, the effect of my 4 fortify alchemy is listed as only 20%. If I drink and then equip, the active effect of my alchemy is listed as 39%.

However, if I press tab and then items. The effects of my items improve the same way. They all list that each of my fortify alchemy apparels, that usually give 20% fortify alchemy now produces 39% fortify alchemy.

I think the issue may be several folds.

Perhaps the number listed on active effect is the one that's accurate instead of the number listed on item?

Comment: [Maybe it was patched](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Thread:252227)? Big exploits like this usually do get fixed.  Someone in that link even described how they made an enchantment that after sometime went back down to a normal number.  So people say its patched, some say it isn't.  I'm betting it is.

Comment: It's not patched as of 1.9. It's patched by skyrim unofficial patch. But I don't install that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The glitch is not patched.

Basically I tried again. This time I have ingredients for fortify enchanting too.

What happens is I tried to drink restoration and go ahead try to create fortify enchanting.

Turns out the number that shows up is bad.

I reload again this time I drink restoration and I remove my fortify alchemy gear and put it back on.

This time it works and now I have 22k% alchemy gears.

It seems that if I do not take off fortify alchemy gears and drink fortify restoration that fortify restoration will improve fortify restoration potions. That number is the one showing up on UI.

I forget where. Maybe in inventory and may be in active effect. They differs.

The way to do this is to drink restoration and wear alchemy gear. Whether you unequip fortify alchemy gear before or after you drink restoration potion doesn't seem to matter. At least not to my knowledge.

Comment: downvoters reveal your self and your reasons. looks like everything i did is downvoted. okay what?

Comment: It's working. The key is to unequip and equip the fortify alchemy gear after drinkin restoration potion.

However, I forget where the hell I see the UI showing that fortify alchemy stats?

Answer (score 1):

Today is the 22th october 2018 and i can confirm the echanting/restoration glitch is still working. I am playing on the nintendo switch and the skyrim-switch-edition which contains all 3 dlcs.(but i also know from a friend it is still possible on pc)

**If some people still not get this glitch to work here are some valuable reminders that helped me a lot:**

**Make sure to savety save before starting the whole glitch-process!!!**

*
Make sure you have 4 gear-parts equipped all enchanted with "Created potions are x% more powerfull"(helm, ring, necklace, gauntlets, etc)

*
Also make sure your alchemy skill tree has at least "alchemist on 2/5", "Physician checked" and "Benefactor checked" (!!! very important !!!) without that skilling, it will take very long or impossible-long to stack enough %boosts together within 60sec.

*
To start correctly, always only create one restoration potion, go out of alchemy table, drink it, unequip and requip gear. and repeat making potion.
Important to keep in mind: you will need to do it at least 10 times or more depending on your alchemy skill and starting gear %-bonus. Also **you need to do it quickly** because potions only last 60 sec and that is where stress comes into play.

You definitely will experience a fall back of % displayed on your potions over time. That is because after 60sec when you continue making stronger potions your very first potion effects will run out. Skyrim calculates this %boost as a stack of multiplications.
Thats why even the smallest bonus in the beginning can have a big negative effect when running out.

**SO JUST KEEP MAKING POTIONS AND DRINKING POTIONS FAST!!!** depending on how fast you can manage through inventory you should get a big % boost after your 20th potion or something. 
Don't take your time too much scrolling through alchemy table or inventory. The timer is running in the back most of the time.

*
Keep in mind the very checkpoint in this procedure is not enchanting gear with fortify alchemy but in creating very strong restoration potions which will have very high %values still after the 60sec mark run out.

Last note: try making restoration potions only with about ~100% - ~1000% and make more of them with the same value. Store them in your house and maybe duplicate them if you want 
so you don't have to stress yourself with the 60sec limitation again. When you have f.e. 20 of the 100%-restoration-potions you can try drinking 2-4 then create 1-3 enchanting potions, drink them and enchant some gear. If the effect is to strong or low rearrange the number of restoration potions.

*Last note very important. making to strong potions will make the %number to flip into negativ because of how skyrim handles high values. If you gonna make a gamesave with items with negativ values the game will very likely crash. **Make sure to savety save before starting the whole glitch-process!!!**

Hope that was helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the unofficial mod installed the glitch WILL NOT WORK. You must uninstall the unofficial mod. That mod patches all glitches and no glitches will work if it is installed

Answer (score -2):

It's probably because this exploit is **patched**. If you are in the latest update of Skyrim, this method won't work for you.

Comment: many says it's still working. It's patched only in unofficial skyrim patch. The developer never patch this. Also even if it's patched it doesn't look like the way it should be.