# How can I do the Fortify Restoration exploit correctly?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I got 100 enchanting, 5/5 enchanter, insightful enchanter, corpus enchanter and extra effect.

As for my Alchemy, it's 50 Alchemy, 3/5 Alchemist, Physician and Benefactor.

I tried so many times to do this glitch, if anyone knows how to do it and answer my question, I would be grateful.

Comment: Related: [How do I create Fortify Alchemy enchantments up to 29%?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/39923/4797) | [Maxing out gear with maxed out smithing, enchanting and alchemy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/45827/4797) | [Enchanting/Alchemy without 5/5 alchemy?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/46727/4797) | [What apparel can I acquire to quickly close the alchemy/enchantment loop?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/49001/4797) | [Why did I fail in using this restoration potion glitch?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/296955/4797)

Answer (score 5):

Quoting [user TodKarlsen on elderscrolls.fandom.com](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Thread:252227):

> - Bring the ingredients for your favorite *Fortify Restoration* potion to your Alchemy Lab. *Salt Pile* is an obvous choice, then the other ingredient is is a matter of what you have a lot of: *Abecean Longfin*, *Cyrodilic Spadetail*, *Small Antlers*, or *Small Pearl*.
> - You'll also want to have the ingredients for *Fortify Enchanting* and *Fortify Smithing* potions.

*Fortify Enchanting* ingredients:

- Blue Butterfly Wing
- Hagraven Claw
- Snowberries
- Spriggan Sap
- Ancestor Moth Wing (Dawnguard)
- Chaurus Hunter Antennae (Dawnguard)
- Spawn Ash (Dragonborn)

*Fortify Smithing* ingredients:

- Blisterwort
- Glowing Mushroom
- Sabre Cat Tooth
- Spriggan Sap

> - Don your best *Fortify Alchemy* gear (5 pieces if you use Circlet & Falmer Helmet).
> - Craft your first *Potion of Fortify Restoration* @ 147% (yours might be lower, my Alchemy skill is at level 100).
> - Drink it, but before exiting the Items menu, go to the Apparel page and doff and re-don one piece of your Alchemy gear. This makes no sense, but it's necessary to bypass a cap which only allows the potions to be 363% stronger.
> - Immediately go to the Alchemy lab and craft the 2nd potion @ 363%, exit alchemy and drink the 363 potion.  Go to the Apparel page and doff and re-don one piece of your Alchemy gear.
> - 3rd potion @ 427%; 4th potion @ 1165%; 5th @ 4428%; 6th @ 41573%; 7th @ 3075947%; and so on, but you risk crashing the program.
> - Then make your *Fortify Enchanting* and *Fortify Smithing* potions, and whatever other potions you want insanely powerful.

Check the thread linked above for more information on using the exploit (note, for example, that it has been patched by the Unofficial Skyrim Patch (which got 'unpatched' by [this mod](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/34302)), and that the values depend on your skills, and other variables).

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GmUtltvUQX0)'s an amusing video by The Spiffing Brit showing you the same process, along with a few more exploits.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need your alchemy and enchanting at level 100. And you'll need 5/5 enchanting and alchemy.

Craft a full set of armor for fortify alchemy. I believe each armor piece should increase it by 40%, I may be wrong. Before you craft the potion of restoration you want to make sure you take off everything from your favorites list and put your set of fortify alchemy armor set onto your favorites list so it'll be much quicker to take on and off

#1. Craft the potion of fortify restoration.

#2. Drink the potion of fortify restoration.

#3. Go to your favorites list and take off all pieces of your fortify alchemy armor set and immediately put them all back on.

#4 Rinse and repeat steps 1 through 3

You can probably do this up to four times before you need to start making the potions you're going to keep. The reason why is because the potions of fortify restoration's effects stack. So the moment you start doing the glitch you only have 30 seconds. Once you go through the steps about 6-7 times then you make the potions you're going to keep.

When you think the percentage is high enough just make like 10 or 12 or however many potions you want to make. And the percentage should be like in the millions or billions.

The way the other guy has you doing it it'll take forever for you to get it into the millions. Because he has you only taking off one armor piece. Once you do it the 5th or 6th time the percentage will start to drop off because the first potion of restorations effect will end.

The way this glitch works is whenever you drink the fortify restoration potion and you take off an armor piece and put it back on, it's going to fortify the percentage on that armor piece. So for example on the first potion the fortify alchemy percentage on your armor piece is going to go from 20% to something like 150% or something around there. So when you take off all pieces of the armor set and put them back on, all the percentages are going to go up.

Comment: You don't *need* Alchemy or Enchanting level 100 or the best Fortify Alchemy gear, it just helps speed up the process. Can you also point out what your answer improves over or how it enhances the other answer?